# Can I use saveOrUpdate method with DynamicUpdate annotation?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

Hello I'm new to Hibernate.

Can I use `saveOrUpdate` method with `DynamicUpdate` annotation on entity class?

Can someone who can explain to me when should I use `saveOrUpdate`, `save` and `update` methods? Or whaat are the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: Question in current form is too broad. Narrow it down to specific issue you face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DynamicUpdate](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-downside-of-version-less-optimistic-locking/) is used when you to have the UPDATE statement include only the columns that have been changed, as opposed to all entity columns.

If the entity is already associated to the current Session (like when loading it using `Session.get()` or `Session.load()`), the [dirty checking mechanism](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/) will automatically detected any change and issue the UPDATE on [flush time](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-flush-strategies/).

The `save` is used to change the entity state from TRANSIENT to PERSISTED and it's only useful when you are saving new objects into the database.

The 'update' method is used to re-associate a detached entity.

The `saveOrUpdate` combines both these methods, but again this is only meant when the entity in question is not yet associated to the current Session. This method makes the entity managed so that Hibernate can automatically synchronize the entity with the associated database row.